# empty string error when binding parameters - indirect splatting

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, splat

I trying to run the this job with paramaters

```
    $courses =  { 
            param($securitytoken_path_a1  ,$EmailPasswordPath_a1 ,$EmailTo_a1)
            Write-Host $securitytoken_path_a1 | Format-Table -Property *
            C:\Users\so\Desktop\CanvasColleagueIntergration\PowerShells\DownloadInformation.ps1 -securitytoken_path ($securitytoken_path_a1) -emailPasswordPath $EmailPasswordPath_a1 -object "courses" -EmailTo $EmailTo_a1 -test $false
            }
```

I am passing these parameters

```
$args1 = @{ "securitytoken_path_a1"  = "C:\Credentials\CANVAS_API_PROD_FRANCO.TXT" ; "EmailPasswordPath_a1" = "C:\Credentials\EMAILFRANCO.txt"; "EmailTo_a1" = 'fpettigrosso@holyfamily.edu'}
```

when I invoke the job with this command it fails

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $courses -Name "Test" -ArgumentList $args1
```

when I try to see what is the issue I get the error back

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'emailPasswordPath' because it is an empty string.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [DownloadInformation.ps1], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,DownloadInformation.ps1
>       + PSComputerName        : localhost

help

Comment: `Start-Job` only support positional argument binding. Thus you passing `Hashtabe` to `$securitytoken_path_a1` parameter and nothing to `$EmailPasswordPath_a1` and `$EmailTo_a1`.

Comment: should I just change the parameter in the $course to just accept an hashtable then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting): the ability to pass a set of parameter values via a *hashtable* (or, less commonl, via an array) to a command.

*Generally*, in order to signal the *intent to splat*, a *special sigil* - `@` is required, so as to distinguish it from a single argument that just happens to be a hashtable:

- `$args1` passes a *single* argument that happens to be a hashtable.
- `@args1` - note how sigil `$` has been replaced with `@` - tells PowerShell to apply *splatting*, i.e., to consider the hashtable's key-value pairs to be parameter-name-value pairs (note that the hashtable keys mustn't start with `-`, which is implied)

However, splatting only works *directly* for a given command, and **you cannot *relay* a splatted hashtable via a command's single parameter**.
That is, attempting to use `-ArgumentList @args1` actually *fails*.

[Your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755109/45375) works around that by passing the hashtable as-is to the script block and then explicitly accessing that hashtable's entries one by one.

An alternative solution is to **use the hashtable argument to apply splatting *inside the script block***:

```
$courses = { 
  param([hashtable] $htArgs) # pass the hashtable - to be splatted later - as-is
  $script = 'C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\CanvasColleagueIntergration\PowerShells\DownloadInformation.ps1'
  & $script @htArgs  # use $htArgs for splatting
}
```

Note, however, that the **target command's parameter names must match the hashtable keys exactly** (or as an unambiguous prefix, but that's ill-advised), so the `_a1` suffix would have to be removed from the keys.

If modifying the input hashtable's keys is not an option, you can use the following command to create a modified copy whose keys have the `_a1` suffix removed:

```
# Create a copy of $args1 in $htArgs with keys without the "_a1" suffix.
$args1.Keys | % { $htArgs = @{} } { $htArgs.($_ -replace '_a1$') = $args1.$_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the parameters in the `$courses` so it will take a hashtable

```
$courses =  { 
            param($a1)
            Write-Host $a1.securitytoken_path_a1 | Format-Table -Property *
            C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\CanvasColleagueIntergration\PowerShells\DownloadInformation.ps1 -securitytoken_path $a1.securitytoken_path_a1 -emailPasswordPath $a1.EmailPasswordPath_a1 -object "courses" -EmailTo $a1.EmailTo_a1 -test $false
            }
```